# search association having class_name

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i have a Book model looking like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', touch: true
  belongs_to :translator, class_name: 'User'
end
```

How can i search for books with specific author name? i join the tables first:

```
Book.joins(:author).joins(:translator)
```

But i cant chain

```
.where('authors.name = "Tolkien"')
```

because there is no "authors" table in the database. is

```
.where('users.name = "Tolkien"')
```

a safe approach here? is there no risk concerning both translators and authors being users in fact?
(select() method is not an option, i need activerecord::relation here)

Comment: Please share the database structure. What happens when the book has _two authors_? _three translators_?

Comment: you  can use `where({author: {name: 'Jon'}, translator: {name: 'Doe'}})` or write the join manually and give it a name manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass table name in query

```
Book.joins(:author).where(users: {name: 'Tolkien'})
```

> is `.where('users.name = "Tolkien"')` a safe approach here?

If you are concerned about two associations using same table you might need to add a field to distinguish them

For ex. a boolean field `author` and use condition with association which will solve the problem

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, -> { where(author: true) }, class_name: 'User', touch: true
  belongs_to :translator, -> { where(author: false) }, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Comment: its not a solution i can use since user can be an author for one book and translator for the other

Comment: Then are you ok with the fact that the query will return  the books where the user is author as well as translator